# What's the precedence of ** wrt unary - in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

The precedence of `**` wrt unary `-` is the same as its behavior in both standard math notation and common programming languages such as Python, i.e.

```
-2**4 acts like -(2**4)
```

up to Groovy 2.4. Is it changing to the nonstandard

```
-2**4 acts like (-2)**4
```

in Groovy 2.5 onwards?

Notes:

1. I can't find any online discussion on this breaking change from a standard behavior to a non-standard one besides http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-groovy-users/201506.mbox/%3C5572D4C8.8070605%40asert.com.au%3E on the Apache mailing list and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7428 on the Apache issue tracker.
2. The groovy grammar https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/antlr/groovy.g clearly makes a special case of `math power operator (**) (without ++(prefix)/--(prefix)/+(unary)/-(unary))`. The behavior of `**` wrt the pre-incr/decr operators could very well be wrong but that's a separate discussion.

Comment: why bother asking SO this? let them sort this out in the mailing list. or you could change the question into "why is -(2**3) in groovy 2.5 so bork" and add above as anwer.

Comment: the change was made to give `++2**3` and `2**3++` a reasonable behavior, in example something that behaves more equal. unary minus was intended to change. Would have been nice to see that on the mailing lists instead

Comment: @cfrick I've changed the question to something more technical and hopefully more suitable for SO.

Comment: @blackdrag I thought the behavior of `**` with unary `-` and with the pre-incr/decr operators are two separate discussions, as I put in note 2. Or are you saying their respective behaviors can't be unlinked, and that `**` behavior with pre-incr/decr is changing to match post-incr/decr **at the expense of** `**` behavior with unary `-` becoming nonstandard?

Comment: Why did you choose an odd power? As it doesn't show and difference between the two. i.e. `-(2**3) == (-2)**3` but `-(2**4) != (-2)**4`

Comment: @weston I've changed the example in the question.

Comment: @GavinGrover I am trying to say that matching the behavior of `++2**3` with `2**3++` was the motivation for the change. If the change also made `-2**4` act different, then maybe the change did something it should not have done. I assume the change happened by chance, but was noticed, documented and then questioned. I am positive undoing the change for unary minus can be done while keeping the new behavior for increment and decrement